# Can we do all things using native JavaScript rather than using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well nowadays I am learning jQuery. So I was just coding and I thought that is it possible to do all the things using JavaScript instead of using jQuery?

Comment: Well jQuery IS written in JavaScript...

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Too Broad? I don't think so.

Comment: I don't agree this question is opinion-based; it is an indisputable fact that jQuery is built on top of JavaScript and as far as the programming functionality is concerned, the very existence of jQuery indicates that one can do "all things using native JavaScript rather than using jQuery"

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you can but you have to go through a long long way. But re-inventing the wheel is never a wise thing to do. The **browsers does not know about the jQuery**, `jQuery` is basically a `javascript` library, that exposes user friendly functions that have javascript behind them.

Comment: "Converted" isn't exactly true. :) jQuery itself is JavaScript, no more, no less.

Comment: Browser does not translate jQuery but jQuery exposes user friendly functions that have javascript behind them.

Comment: JQuery IS JavaScript, no translation needed. It is a library to simplify the use of JavaScript.

Comment: wow you have given me very good exampaple ...

Comment: well I just wanted to know the core of the jquery and I got it

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is a library written in JavaScript.
You cannot do anything in jQuery that cannot be done in JavaScript.

jQuery was designed to make client-side scripting easier, e.g. by using a CSS selector syntax to select DOM elements and the ease with which it could then traverse these and modify their content. It also irons out a lot of cross-browser compatibility issues (e.g. adding event handlers) and takes a lot of common tasks that require multiple lines of JavaScript code to accomplish, and wraps them into methods that you can call with a single line of code (e.g. AJAX).

But, at the end of the day, it's still JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a library written in Javascript, so yes - anything you can do in jQuery can be done in Javascript. It's not a different language, or interpreted by the browser in some special way - it's just javascript.

Comment: thanks you v. much dear